# Polylogarithm : reference request for proof of integral representation

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, polylogarithms

On page 494 of the book *Integrals and series, volume I : elementary functions,* Gordon and Breach, 1986, by A. P. Prudnikov, Y. A. Brychkov, and O.I. Marichev, (perhaps translated from Russian), the following integral representation of the polylogarithm $Li_{s+1}$ is given without proof :

\begin{equation}
Li_{s+1}(z) = \frac{z}{\Gamma(s+1)} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\log ^s(t)}{t(t-z)} dt
\end{equation}

for $z,s \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|arg(1-z)| < \pi$, Re$(s)>-1$. $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function.

Does anyone know where a proof can be found ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm cites in case $s$ is a nonnegative integer:  "See equation (4) in section 2 of Borwein, Borwein and Girgensohn's article *Explicit evaluation of Euler sums* (1994)."

Comment: Thanks Mr. Edgar. In fact I was just calculating, it is not very hard to show by differentiating that the function defined as above satisfies the recurrence relation $\frac{\partial Li_{s+1}}{\partial z} = \frac{Li_s(z)}{z}$ which is a defining property of the polylogarithms...

Comment: True, it is not hard to prove this (write $\frac{1}{t(t-z)}$ as a power series in $z$, then integrate term-by-term, using $$\int_1^\infty \frac{\log(t)^s}{t^k}\,dt = \frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{(k-1)^{s+1}}$$).  But the question is not about how to prove it, but about where a proof can be found.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is "where can a proof be found", here is one reference (but there must be many others):

[An Integral Representation for the Polylogarithm Function and Some Special Values](https://www.scipress.com/BMSA.8.6)

Comment: thank you very much for the reference'